# SSL Error while Connecting to Apple Sandbox for Receipt Validation

Tags: macos, cocoa, receipt-validation

3 out of 4 connections fails while trying to validate the receipt using apple sandbox URL.Is anyone experiencing the same issue?

***https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt***

```
 Connection 3: encountered error(3:-9816)
 2020-04-03 20:30:18.834825+0530 App[6312:266644] Task <AD18FA15-D34F-4428-BD0A-107AAAAAF555>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1200 [3:-9816])
    the upload task returned an error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000cac660 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9816, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
```

[image]

Comment: Same here... Only today. Did you see any communication about this issue from Apple?

Comment: @janosdupai No.. this is my first upload to App store.

Comment: I hope, they detected this issue, and now they are working on fix it.